Meromorphic functions are rational

Let $f:\hat{\mathbb{C}} \to \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ be an analytic function, i.e., $f\restriction_{\mathbb{C}}$ and $f(\frac{1}{z})\restriction_{\mathbb{C}}$ are meromorphic or are constant taking the value $\infty$. Then $f$ is rational.

As $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is compact and $f^{-1}(\infty)$ is closed and discrete, there is a finite number of poles:$z_1,z_2, \dots, z_n$; let $d_i=\mathcal{ord}(z_i,f); i=1,2, \dots,n$; then $f(z)\prod_{i=1}^{n}(z-z_i)^{-d_i}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ and so could have at most a pole at $\infty$; if it has a pole, $f(z)\prod_{i=1}^{n}(z-z_i)^{-d_i}$ is a polynomial function, but how do we justify in the case where $\infty$ is a removable singularity?

Use Liouville's theorem to conclude that the product is constant.
